# How to make lower letters in PHP, except the first one in a string?

Tags: php, substr

This is my string : `"JIMMY"`.

This is my try :

```
 $string = "JIMMY";
 $string= strtolower(substr($string,1));
 echo $string;
```

the result of the echo is : `immy` and I want to be : `Jimmy`. How can I manage that? thx

Comment: `ucfirst(strtolower($string))`

Comment: @deceze thx deceze. Why my post is voted down ?

Comment: What do you want if the string is originally `jiMMy`? Do you want `jimmy` or `Jimmy`?

Comment: I read the title "How to make love letters in PHP" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need,

```
echo ucfirst(strtolower($string));
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8LArw9)**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ucfirst function](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ucfirst.php)

```
$string = "JIMMY";
$string= ucfirst(strtolower($string));
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the handy PHP function `ucfirst()`, it makes a string's first character uppercase:

`echo ucfirst(strtolower($string));`

A side note: The 'alphabetic' is determined by the **current locale**. For instance, in the default "C" locale characters such as German `umlaut-a` (ä) will not be converted.

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

Comment: `ucfirst("äÄÄÄÄ") == "äÄÄÄÄ"` with C locale?

Answer (score 1):

This will change the rest of the word to lowercase, and leave the first letter alone.

```
$string = ($string == "" ? "" : $string[0] . strtolower(substr($string, 1)));
```

All the other answers make the first letter uppcase even if it was originally lowercase. That's not what you asked for.

Comment: Extreme overkill for someone who asks for such a basic thing. I don't think OP even understood your code. Besides, I reinventing the wheel is always a great idea, sigh.

Comment: What wheel am I reinventing? My solution is not equivalent to `ucfirst`. He didn't say he wanted the first letter to be uppercase, he said he wants everything else to be lowercase. I'm still waiting for an answer to my question in the comments.

Comment: No excuse for such a childish "the others are doing it wrong, you didn't ask for what they answer". This is an insult to the OP claiming he is unable to figure out what he asked for. Rude.